# Convert Near Pointer to Far Pointer

Tags: c, pointers, dos, 16-bit

I have some code that reads in a file to a 32K near buffer and needs to copy the data to a memory location pointed to by a `__far` pointer. I need to use the `_fmemcpy` function to do it, but when it gets called it locks up the program.

```
unsigned char *working_buffer;
working_buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);

_fmemcpy((unsigned char __far *)p_image_data, (unsigned char __far *)working_buffer, working_length);
```

I've simplified this function call slightly, and if needed I can post the rest of the code for my file loading function. The compiler (which is Digital Mars C 16bit, small memory model) compiles this code without error or warning and runs up until this function, where it simply freezes up. My best guess is that it's not really converting `working_buffer` to a `__far` pointer. But I'm really not sure.

Comment: When looking on the Digital Mars Compiler documentation, to convert a _near pointer to a _far pointer, it is necessary to use the macro MK_FP() as `fp = MK_FP( getDS(), (unsigned) np );`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that information. Could you actually post a link to the page that has that info on it? I couldn't find it anywhere. Also, this turns out that it isn't a problem with converting near pointer to a far pointer, just me doing something really stupid. But nevertheless, I really needed that information.

Comment: You can find all details at ["Digital Mars - 16 Bit Pointer Types and Type Modifiers"](http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/pointers16.html).

Comment: Hmm... maybe use a better compiler. Every 16-bit x86 compiler I've used automatically converts near pointers to far, by automatically combining the DS segment value with the near offset. All you'd need to is `_fmemcpy(p_image_data, working_buffer, working_length)`, assuming a prototype for `_fmemcpy` was in scope.

Comment: It might actually do this. My problem turned out to not be caused by this conversion as I thought, but it's still just good to know. Really though, Digital Mars seems to be the best 16 bit compiler. Open Watcom has way too many bugs, and the other compilers all have to be run in DOS.